# Silverlight Javascript - Access and setting value of xaml's textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, silverlight

I have a text box named myTextbox in my xaml page, my question is how can i set it's text through javascript from my aspx page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a public string property in the silverlight side, mark it with the `ScriptableMemberAttribute`, and bind the textbox `text` property to this public property. The property marked with the `ScriptableMemberAttribute` is visible to javascript.

The code to access a silverlight property from javascript depends on the names you have used for those objects, but you have examples here on how to access them:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221414%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

More info on making silverlight objects visible to javascript :
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645085%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

Comment: I'm sure they do, however as a long time contributor to SO I have an interest in the quality of the answers actually here at SO.  Sometimes it is more pratical to read details from a link but in this case it would not take a great deal of code to demonstrate the answer without requiring the reader to hop to yet another site.  That was the original goal of SO to be the go to site for programming __answers__, not just another forum with links to possible answers.

Comment: In not going to enter in a discussion about this, but I posted an answer, and added two links for reference just in case he needs more details. I see your point, but I also think that not all the answers must include code forcibly.